# How to pass a raw type in Scala?

Tags: generics, scala

How can I pass a parameter to a Java method with a raw type in its method signature?  My example API is as follows:

```
class P<T> {}

class Q {
    public void f(P p[]) {}
}
```

And my attempt to call it from Scala looks like this:

```
val q = new Q()
val p = new P()
val p_array = Array(p)
q.f(p_array)
```

Which generates the following compiler error:

```
type mismatch;
found   : Array[P[Nothing]]
required: Array[P[_]]
q.f(p_array)
```

Parameterizing p as type P[Any] doesn't help either.  I'm using 2.8 RC6.

By way of background, the API which has caused me this problem is something called [org.teleal.cling.model.meta.LocalDevice](http://teleal.org/projects/cling/core/apidocs/org/teleal/cling/model/meta/LocalDevice.html)  The constructor looks like it takes a parameterized argument 'deviceServices'.  However, the type parameter 'LocalService' *also*
takes a parameter, not supplied, resulting in the awkward method signature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply make the array instantiation explicit (shown in compilable form):

```
object PQ {
    def
    main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val q = new Q()
        val p = new P()
        val p_array = Array[P[_]](p)
        q.f(p_array)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll have to puzzle over what that means, but much better to puzzle over a working example than a broken one!